# no input device is detected ubuntu 22.04 - no microphone is detected

Tags: sound, 22.04, microphone, devices, input-devices

I just installed ubuntu 22.04 and i'm facing an issue is that there is no input device detected .
i tried to use pavucontrol but it doesn't work :

**lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3**

```
    01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2291] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
06:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
06:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 60)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_acp6x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt
06:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
07:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:161f]
```

i'm not yet allowed to add images sorry , but the issue is that in settings - sound - input section is grayed out .

External mic is working fine ...

Please advice .
Thank you

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`